Is there a way for a pedestrian with a bicycle to cross from Spain to Portugal near the Cedillo dam
I am a cycle tourist. I would like to cross from Spain to Portugal near the Cedillo dam.
Map
https://maps.app.goo.gl/TfbvNf7Ud9N3YQVF8
Wikipedia's entry https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presa_de_Cedillo
Google maps shows the dam wall is closed for public crossing.
Google search shows a bridge is planned for 2026.
Can any one confirm?
Any regular and reliable ways of crossing the Tajo River near the Cedillo dam?

There is a bridge on the N18 to the southwest?

@JonCuster I think that's an answer. Both Google maps and openstreetmap confirm it. 12 km as the crow flies, and about 34 by road
